# Ionic 2 - tabs in footer & subfooter & content area

Tags: user-interface, ionic2, ionic3

What is the approach with Ionic if we need to implement a Page where tabs only change a subfooter space while main content area remains the same (there is a google map there and tabs are changing different instruments that user can apply to it).

I read all the docs from ionic framework but its hard to understand how to search for a pattern that I need get accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to use [`Segments`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/) since the `Tabs` would force you have different pages for each tab.

You can create a `ion-footer` at the bottom, and place there the `SegmentButtons`. Then you can set the height of the map to be, for instance, 60% of the content, and then add a div with the rest of the height (40%). Inside of that div, you'd place the content of each segment. It would be something like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Your PageName</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>   
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <!-- Map section -->
    <div class="map" style="height:60%;">
        <!-- Here you would display the map -->
    </div>

    <!-- Additional UI section -->
    <div class="additional-div" style="height:40%;">

        <div [ngSwitch]="selectedSection">

            <div *ngSwitchCase="'tabButtonOne'">
                <!-- Content to show when the fist tab button is selected -->
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>

            <div *ngSwitchCase="'tabButtonTwo'">
                <!-- Content to show when the second tab button is selected -->
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>

            <div *ngSwitchCase="'tabButtonThree'">
                <!-- Content to show when the third tab button is selected -->
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSection" color="light">
            <ion-segment-button value="tabButtonOne">
                Tab button 1
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="tabButtonTwo">
                Tab button 2
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="tabButtonThree">
                Tab button 3
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

And then in your component code the property that we use to store the selected segment's value:

```
@Component(...)
export class YourPage {

    // Select the first segment by default...
    public selectedSection = 'tabButtonOne';

    // ...
}
```